# PBI Create new table containing valued from a filtered table

Tags: powerbi

G'day,

I have the below table:

[image]

I have filtered that table with slicers on my report to only show trucks which match Customer CUST001 for example

[image]

Is it possible to create a table in PowerBi to list the [Truck] column with the slicerer filtered values only?

[image]

It's important to note that the slicer can and will be changed on the report which is where I am stumped as the filter on the truck list must match the slicer. It cannot be done in powerquerry

Comment: Unsure on your ask - you cannot create a Calculated Table based on a slicer as these are calculated at dataset refresh time, so are essentially static. If you are meaning a Table visual, then simply place a Table visual with that one column. Perhaps you are wanting a list of the filtered trucks to use in another calculation - if so, please update your question with your scenario.